# In Debian, what is the lifecycle of the packages that can be updated on Stable?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I did read the relevant part of the Debian Handbook (https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.release-lifecycle.html) to learn more about the lifecycle of a release. I found a lot of info, but some of my questions remain unanswered:

- Packages are tested for a long time before being put in Debian Stable, and have to pass through Unstable and Testing. Yet, how are managed the packages that are directly updatable through Stable (with an `apt upgrade`) ? Are there just emergency security updates or it is more broad than that?
- If Stable is considered a copy of Testing at a given time, could Testing be considered as a rolling release (i.e. one could just stay forever on Testing and update everything through `apt upgrade`s) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package uploads for stable are possible for more than security updates; basically, a targeted fix for a severe bug will typically be approved. The details are given in [the Debian developer’s reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.en.html#special-case-uploads-to-the-stable-and-oldstable-distributions). Updates go to the updates repository first, and are folded into the distribution in the following point release (10.9, 10.10, etc.).

One can stay forever on testing, but it’s not a rolling release. [The Debian wiki page on testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) gives details. The main issues are that testing can end up frozen for long periods of time, *e.g.* in the run-up to a release (when the whole distribution is frozen) or during complex package transitions (when dependency trees are frozen), and that testing doesn’t receive security support, so security issues can take a while to fix there.

Comment: And, possibly of interest, if you _really_ do want a rolling release, you probably need Debian Sid unless you need guarantees of reliability (Sid generally works correctly most of the time for the most common configurations, but sometimes after an update you have to put a Sid system back together with duct-tape and chewing gum).

Comment: Back around 2000 we used to say that Sid was more stable than any RedHat release ending in ".0" :) RedHat has gotten better since then, but sid is still pretty good.

Comment: @Austin and even then, Sid also nearly freezes before a release — see right now for example. (I’m assuming people looking for a rolling release want a constant flow of updates; perhaps that’s not the case.)